# Why does a linear regression placeholder have shape [1, 1] in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I've been reading this guide on tensorflow: https://medium.com/all-of-us-are-belong-to-machines/the-gentlest-introduction-to-tensorflow-248dc871a224

...and mostly, I see what's happening.

However, the linear model in the [example code](https://github.com/nethsix/gentle_tensorflow/blob/master/code/linear_regression_one_feature.py) defines the linear model like this:

```
# Model linear regression y = Wx + b
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1])
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1,1]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]))
product = tf.matmul(x,W)
y = product + b
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1])

# Cost function sum((y_-y)**2)
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y_-y))

# Training using Gradient Descent to minimize cost
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.0000001).minimize(cost)
```

The question is: Why is `Wx + b` represented with these values:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1])
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1,1]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]))
```

? `[None, 1]`, `[1, 1]`? Why `[None, 1]` for x and `[1, 1]` for W?

If `[1, 1]` is 1 element of size 1, then why is b just `[1]`, what does that mean? 1 element of size 0?

> For W = tf.Variable, the first '1' is feature, house size, and the 2nd '1' is output, house price.

Does that mean if I was trying to represent the model, say:

```
y = Ax + Bz
```

That means I have two 'features' (x and z) and that my A and B values should be shaped [2, 1]? It doesn't seem right...

This seems utterly unlike what is done in [polynomial regression](https://github.com/pkmital/tensorflow_tutorials/blob/master/python/03_polynomial_regression.py#L22), where weight factors are shape `[1]`. Why is this different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think maybe you should learn something like linear algebra.

Let's start with this line `# Model linear regression y = Wx + b` which is the first line in the code you post. Actually, it means two matrix operations.

First one is `Wx`, that means matrix `X` matrix multiply `x`. In your case, means:

```
[x11, x21, x31, ..., xn1]T * [w] = [x11*w, x21*w, x31*w, ..., xn1*w]T
```

Let `Wx` as `R`(Result), we can rewrite `Wx + B` into `R + B`. This is the second matrix operation. In your case, means:

```
[x11*w, x21*w, x31*w, ..., xn1*w]T + [b] = [x11*w + b, x21*w + b, x31*w + b, ..., xn1*w + b]T
```

So if you have more than one features in your input, and want to output multiple results, the definition of model should be:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, your_input_features])
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([your_input_features, your_output_features]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([your_output_features]))
product = tf.matmul(x,W)
y = product + b
```

Comment: That's what the article says! The question I'm asking is *why*. Here is an alternative solution that does *not* do that: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pkmital/tensorflow_tutorials/master/python/02_linear_regression.py Why would you do *this* instead of *that*.

Comment: @Doug Actually, there is no difference between these two solution if you just have one input feature and just one output feature. But the solution posted in your question can be easily modified to be used in multiple input features and multiple output features situation.

Comment: @Doug So in another word, it is more likely a problem about coding but not the structure of model.

Comment: @Doug Oh, I found I did something wrong in the original answer, the shape of output of `y = Wx + b` should be `[None, 1]`. Sorry about that if gives you any inconvenience.

Comment: So the comment 'For W = tf.Variable, the first '1' is feature, house size, and the 2nd '1' is output, house price.' is just wrong? The first element of the shape `[1, 1]` for W is the size of the *input* vector for x; ie. the number of input params, not the size of the *output*, because we are doing x * W, not W * x.

Comment: Thank you helping explain this to me, you're right; this is just representing the same problem as a matrix operation instead of a linear operation; the comments on the article were confusing to me.

Answer (score 0):

The original author should have chosen the shape as `[1, 1]` because she/he wanted to have a more general function than plain scalar product.

This way, you can change the shape to `[1, d]` to have `d` features for each sample.

Of course one should also change the shape of `x` to `d` then.

Comment: Why would you want d features to model `Wx + b`? Why is W `[1, 1]` when b is `[1]`?

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with linear algebra ?

A placeholder of shape [None, 1] means unlimited rows and 1 column.
A placeholder of shape [1, 1] means 1 row and 1 column.

Shape [1, 1] and [1] are different in that sense:

- [1]    => plh = [x]
- [1, 1] => plh = [[x]]

Then tf.matmul compute the dot product: x.W and add b.
In order for tensorflow to work, the tensors must be of similar shape, that's why W is of shape [1, 1] and not just [1].

Let us have:

- x = [[1], [2], [3]]
- W = [[10]]
- b = [[9], [8], [7]]

Then:

- tf.matmul(x, W) = [[10], [20], [30]]
- tf.matmul(x, W) + b  = [[19], [28], [27]]

I hope this answer your question

Comment: How is x [[1], [2], [3]] when  `xs = np.array([[i]]); sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: xs, y_: ys}})`? (It is clearly not). Why is that necessary? Why not model this as a linear operation like Y_pred = tf.add(tf.multiply(X, W), b)?